# Almost all Liouville torus is preserved for small oscillation problems even if we don't use second-order approximation to potential energy, right?

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian-formalism, non-linear-systems, integrable-systems

In small oscillation problems, we use a second-order approximation to the potential energy function (suppose the oscillation is around the point $(0,\cdots, 0)$),
$$
V(x) = V(0) + \frac{\partial^2 V(0)}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}x_ix_j + o(|x|^3),
$$
and by ignoring the $o(|x|^3)$ term, we get a harmonic system, which is completely integrable.

Now I am considering what if we do not ignore the $o(|x|^3)$ term. I read a little bit about [KAM theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Arnold%E2%80%93Moser_theorem), and came up with this idea: we can think of the $o(|x|^3)$ term as the small perturbation of the approximated harmonic system, and **according to KAM theory**, almost all the Liouville torus close to the origin are preserved with a small change in shape, therefore **the motion of the non-perturbed system near the origin can still be viewed as the composition of $n$ periodic motions**, with slightly different periods than the ones of approximated harmonic system.

However, since I am not really familiar with KAM theory, I am not sure whether I have used KAM theory in the correct way. So, **is my idea correct**? And why is it correct or not correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your idea is correct.

Near-integrable Hamiltonian systems such as you describe are the most important application of the KAM theory. So, yes, if the technical conditions are respected (non-degeneracy, smoothness of the perturbation, etc.), most regular behavior is preserved.

From [Scholarpedia](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Kolmogorov-Arnold-Moser_theory#Nearly-integrable_Hamiltonian_systems):

> A **nearly-integrable Hamiltonian system** is a Hamiltonian system governed by a Hamiltonian function of the form $H_\epsilon(y,x)=K(y)+\epsilon P(y,x)$ with $y=(y_1,...,y_n)$ (*action variables*) varying in a domain $B\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and
> $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ (*angle variables*) varying in the standard $n$-dimensional torus $\mathbb{T}^n\ .$
> For $\epsilon=0\ ,$ equations (1) [Hamilton equations] give
> $\dot y=0$
> and
> $\dot x=\partial_y K(y)\ ,$
> hence
> $y=y_0=$ constant
> and $x = x_0 + \omega_0\, t$ (mod $2\pi$),
> with $\omega_0:= \partial_y K\big(y_0\big)\ .$ Thus the torus $\{y_0\}\times \mathbb{T}^n$ is invariant for the flow $\phi^t_{K}\ ,$ and if $\omega_0$ is Diophantine and $\partial_y^2 K(y_0)$ is invertible, then such a torus is  a non-degenerate KAM torus for $H_0=K\ .$
> Since $K(y)$ can be expanded by Taylor's formula as
>
> $K=K(y_0)+\omega_0\cdot (y-y_0)+ \frac{1}{2} \partial_y^2 K(y_0) (y-y_0) \cdot(y-y_0)+ O(|y-y_0|^3|),$
>
> it follows from Kolmogorov's Theorem that
> *for $\epsilon$ small enough such tori persist, giving rise to non-degenerate KAM tori for $H_\epsilon$*.